# NodeJS HTTP server free memory after each request

Tags: node.js

I have a http server using nodejs . When a request incomes , i create some object . When a request is done , Do I have to free these objects ? My RAM increases when have many requests and it doesn't descrease.

Answer (score 1):

No

What you see in RAM is the memory that Node.js is reserving, (I think it s called heap), but it do not always use everything in it.

What you can do to help node however, is set your object to null when they are no longer useful.

If your RAM is totally eaten up, it might be your request don t end somehow, so node don t free the memory allocated to it.